# DatagridView: how to programmatically move the current index to the programmatically selected row?

Tags: vb.net

On a textfield the user can type a name then press a button and the program search the name on the DataGridView and highlight the row of the record

The search and highlight loop

```
For Each row In DataGrid.Rows
    If row.Cells("userName").Value = userNameToSearch Then                
        row.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The loops works fine

Then I need to move the index of the DataGridView to match that row

If I use

```
Dim MyFindedIndex As Integer
MyFindedIndex = DataGrid.CurrentRow.Index
```

I get a 0 even if I know the matched and highlighted row is number 7 by example.

If I understand well I **also need to move the index of the current cell** because is the current cell the one who determine the value of the index

I can do that forcing to move to the index number 7

```
DataGrid.CurrentCell = DataGrid.Item(0, 7)
```

But I need to do that programmatically (find the "7" number)

**Maybe using IndexOf or something like that?**

---

**Solution**

Using Fabio answer!

The column of the **cell needs to be visible**, and that was not the case on my DataGridView because the cell contains a primary key number the user didn't need to see

The solution: one cell for the search, one cell for the position (this one visible)

```
For Each row In DataGrid.Rows
    'Cell to search
    Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = row.Cells("userNumber")
    'Cell to position
    Dim cell2 As DataGridViewCell = row.Cells("userName")
    If cell.Value.ToString().Equals(userNumberToSearch) = True Then                
        DataGrid.CurrentCell = cell2
    Exit For
    End If
Next
```

If the column of the cell was not visible VB Throw System Null Reference

Comment: is it a DataGrid or a DataGridView?

Comment: DataGridView sorry.

Comment: You can grab the row index in your loop `row.Index` or `row.Cells("userName").RowIndex`. You can even get the column index the same way `row.Cells("userName").ColumnIndex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to set `DataGridView.CurrentCell`. Do it in your search loop

```
For Each row In DataGrid.Rows
    Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = row.Cells("userName")
    If cell.Value.ToString().Equals(userNameToSearch) = True Then                
        DataGrid.CurrentCell = cell
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You're code works fine and highlight the row but after that If I ask The DataGrid.CurrentRow.Index I get a Nothing value and not the 7 I'm looking for. Is strange because before calling the other grid to search / select the row that index works fine even if I click on any row, the index change and I use that index to display the info

Comment: I found the solution, the column of the "cell" was hidden on my case (prlmary key) so I need to use a trick. Solution posted below the answer. Thanks.

Comment: yes - you can use only visible cells for `CurrentCell`

Answer (score 1):

For a DataGridView you can use:

```
  Datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex
```

Comment: How? If I use DataGrid.CurrentCell = DataGrid.Item(0, Datagridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex)  I get   "Reference to a non-shared member requires a object reference

Comment: First you should ensure .Index has value

Comment: Sorry I don´t understand. The Index is what I need to know. On the sample is 7 but I need to load that value to a variable to use on the DataGrid.CurrentCell = DataGrid.Item(0, 7) lines

Comment: I found the solution, posted below the answer. Thanks